# Can MAM use non-zero value transactions?

Tags: masked-authenticated-messaging

Can MAM publish messages of 1i that aren't deleted by snapshots?

Comment: How about a bit more context?

Comment: I'm not sure there is much else for me to say. instantlink set me straight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no value transfer within MAM.

It's a messaging api

https://github.com/iotaledger/MAM

Answer (score 2):

1. MAM does not support value transfer
2. All transactions (also the ones that send `1i`) are deleted by a snapshot (on non-permanodes), only the final balances remain.

Therefore if you need transactions to survive across snapshots, you'd better find (or run) a permanode. (The only permanode I know of is run by the admin of thetangle.org for his tangle explorer. But I think there is interest for more.)